# AFIncrementalStore Unrecognized selector -[NSNull length] error

Tags: ios, core-data, afnetworking, afincrementalstore

I'm trying to add AFIncrementalStore to an existing Core Data app with lots of data already in the database. I thought I'd added everything necessary, then I fire up the app, and during the initial fetch requests I get this error:

```
-[NSNull length]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0xNNNNNNN
```

The error itself is fired on the `AFReferenceObjectFromResourceIdentifier` method [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore/blob/298a60cbc9b679f78b0ede45f08e07b23b99b9f3/AFIncrementalStore/AFIncrementalStore.m#L49).

The source of the error appears to creep in in AFIncrementStore.m in the `executeFetchRequest:withContext:error:` method - when it calls `[results valueForKeyPath:kAFIncrementalStoreResourceIdentifierAttributeName]` - the returned array contains one or more `NSNull` values. (find it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore/blob/298a60cbc9b679f78b0ede45f08e07b23b99b9f3/AFIncrementalStore/AFIncrementalStore.m#L422))

The whole library appears to have very little documentation, so I'm sure it's something really 'obvious' that I'm supposed to have done to my code / data model.

Comment: Please some code where you get `NSNull` Value.

Comment: It's from the AFIncrementalStore code itself

Comment: If it is github code. please mention link to github or where available code.

Comment: Ok, have linked to the point in the code on Github

Answer (score 1):

Try doing "Reset Content & Settings" on your iOS simulator. I know this sounds crazy, but I was getting this exact same, inexplicable bug myself (ended up ruining a couple live demo before figuring this out).

"Turn it off and on again" is not the most satisfying solution, but at least it's something.

Comment: I'm getting this error every time I insert an object and then do a fetch. Doesn't AFIS assign a resourceIdentifier to an object upon inserting into the MOC? Have you devised a fix for this? More details in my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800148/afincrementalstore-null-resource-identifier)